# Don't work ssh in GitLab

Tags: ssh, gitlab, gitlab-7

In my one PC command `ssh -T git@github.lcl.loc` work and output `Welcome to GitLab, Anonymous!`.

But in my two PC command output

```
$ ssh -vT git@github.lcl.loc
OpenSSH_4.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Feb 2007
debug1: Connecting to github.lcl.loc [192.168.1.104] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Documents and Settings/n.nozdrin-plotnickij.LCL/.ssh/id
entity type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Documents and Settings/n.nozdrin-plotnickij.LCL/.ssh/id
_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /c/Documents and Settings/n.nozdrin-plotnickij.LCL/.ssh/id
_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debia
n-4+deb7u2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.6
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'github.lcl.loc' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Documents and Settings/n.nozdrin-plotnickij.LCL/.ssh/kno
wn_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Documents and Settings/n.nozdrin-plotnickij.LCL/.
ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /c/Documents and Settings/n.nozdrin-plotnickij.LCL/
.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Documents and Settings/n.nozdrin-plotnickij.LCL/.
ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
git@github.lcl.loc's password:
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
git@github.lcl.loc's password:
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
git@github.lcl.loc's password:
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

I generate new RSA key. Nothing has changed. 
Key was created without a password.

If you enter the password from the user git, get access to the console as user git.

GitLab v7.9.4
GitLab Shell 2.6.2
Install whithout omnibus-gitlab...

Comment: Does your PC1 (the one where it works) include an `%HOME%\.ssh\config` file? Or default `id_rsa(.pub)` private and public ssh keys?

Comment: Not file config. Only public and private key and known_hosts. PC2 analogically.

Comment: Do you have your `id_rsa(.pub)` keys on PC2? [With a public one (`id_rsa.pub`) published in your GitLab repo](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/ssh/README.html)?

Comment: Yes. On PC2 have keys. And public published in Gitlab. But I noticed that in file `/var/opt/gitlab/.ssh/authorized_keys` don't add public key PC2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK. When I noticed that file don't add keys, I delete file `/var/opt/gitlab/.ssh/authorized_keys` and stared command `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`.

This file create. Via web-interface I delete all keys, and add their again.

It worked!